# Capturing logs when Docker container crashes

Tags: docker, logging

My app uses a 3rd party jar which is liable to cause a system crash at random times. We dont want the issue to kill our service so the docker container uses the "always" restart policy.
What I am trying to do now is find a way to capture the logs to see what caused the crash but because the actual docker container is restarted I can't just log onto the crashed docker when the crash happens because the old container that crashed is removed and a new container starts up. Is there any way to push log files onto say amazon S3 after the app crashes but before the docker container is destroyed?

Comment: Mount the logs in a folder on the host machine's filesystem and you're done.

Comment: If you use Kubernetes then you can `kubectl logs --previous` to get exactly this, but it’s...an Investment.

Comment: Its not my application logs that I need to capture as I send them to S3 bucket.  It is the system logs which would help me find what caused the container to crash that I need to capture. Is there some life cycle event in a Docker container that I can use to push the logs to an external folder when the docker container is about to die?

Comment: you can check "docker events" and look for restarts